# One line coding with if statement inside for loop

Tags: python, one-liner

I need help shortening the following code into one line.

```
for i in objects:
    if i not in uniq: 
        uniq.append(i)
```

Im just doing it for a challenge, not going to keep this.

Comment: Have you tried anything in particular?

Comment: How about `uniq = set(objects)`? You haven't really said what the code is supposed to do or what's wrong with the code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, although this is a bad idea for many reasons

```
uniq=[]
objects= [9,9,1,2,3,4,5,5,9,9,15,12,33]
[uniq.append(i) for i in objects if i not in uniq]
print(uniq)
```

outputs:

```
[9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 12, 33]
```

Firstly, from a style/readability perspective it's confusing to read, is 'implicit rather than explicit' it adds no value over your FOR loop except to put everything onto one line for no real benefit.

Secondly, it's hard to modify, it's limited to exactly one operation, which might work now but if you need to add a second operation you have to refactor the whole thing

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: agh it's a bad idea don't do it!

Comment: @Dav_DidHu: See [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest oneliner would be to use a `set`:

```py
uniq = set(objects)
```

If you really need a list, you could of course create one from the set:

```py
uniq = list(set(objects))
```

Comment: No, using set would disturb the order of the list.

Comment: And if you want to sort the list back into the "ordering" of the first list, then you can just throw a `sorted` at it: `sorted(list(set(objects)), key=lambda x: objects.index(x))`

Answer (score 0):

```
objects= [9,9,1,2,3,4,5,5,9,9,15,12,33]    
uniq=[ele for i,ele in enumerate(objects) if objects.index(ele)==i]
```

outputs

```
[9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 12, 33]
```